# how to use auto generated slug as post URL link in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-templates, uuid

i have a UUID primary kay for posts which generates 09cd5677-8e02-4bcb-8895-5e3f79f20a4b this code which i use for link in URL post/09cd5677-8e02-4bcb-8895-5e3f79f20a4b but it looks bad so I add this slug field

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post_id = models.SlugField(default=get_random_string,null=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('postdetails', args=[str(self.post_id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

and now my post is like this - post/TtMgyttnnUzO
so main question is to is it can make similar match of this post/TtMgyttnnUzO like generating similar post slug post/TtMgyttnnUzO so after that it will crush , how can I protect website to get ride of this problem and if there are other better solutions thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100) #Title of the Post
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.post_title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

- Here the **save** method of the model is overridden. The **slugify** function creates a unique slug of the **post_title** and the slug value is saved along with the other values.
- SlugField should always be unique.
- The above solution also works when the **post_title** is updated, A new slug for the updated **post_title** will be generated.

Having a Slug improves readability of the url and the SEO.

Comment: thanks i will test now, some my posts should not have title ,from title required is free , thats why i want to keep post/TtMgyttnnUzO ,  can i use slugify for  post/TtMgyttnnUzO+slugify  and also what type of code is generated by slugify? is it text or numbers only? thanks